# React Native rendering twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When call state from *AsyncStorage* in new page. I found error and then i tried to *console.log* the state in render function i found *console.log* twice, the first console was null and the second was state from *AsyncStorage*. Why it happen? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Add some code, so we could help you.

Comment: Reacts job is to rerender your component when its state changes. Since you are making an async request to some data on the device, your component mounts before the request is finished. It will console.log null then when the data is received, it will re render, and run the console log again showing the data.

Comment: This is normal react behavior.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich Okay thank sir for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

React will call render as many times as it requires to reflect changes on the state object, if you are asynchronously fetching data and updating the state, you will see a console.log message as the component is first rendered, and once again once the data is fetched and the state updated.

In other words, working as expected, if you want to only log whatever message just once, try moving this line to the component constructor or componentDidMount methods.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i understand about how react work